# perf cannot get cache-misses for Linux VM on VMware ESX

Tags: linux, cache, esxi, perf

I interested on measuring CPU cache-misses parameter and came across this tool called perf. I followed the wiki and able to get the cache-misses when this command is run on physical machine

```
[root@supermicro ~]# perf stat -e cache-misses dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000          1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB) copied, 0.539799 s, 949 MB/s

Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

            55,435 cache-misses

       0.540932058 seconds time elapsed
```

When run on Linux VM that sit on VMware ESX machine, i got 0 cache-misses

```
[root@cw-centos62 fioFiles]# perf stat -e cache-misses dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB) copied, 0.593885 s, 862 MB/s

 Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

                 0 cache-misses

       0.595547968 seconds time elapsed
```

Is this normal? If yes, is there any other way to get the cache-misses information for Linux VM that sit on VMware ESX?

Cw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counter and some others are not available in VMWare virtual machines.

Reference: [Performance applications that use Hardware Performance Monitoring Counters do not display information correctly (2015931)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2015931)

Some of the latest VMWare products do have an option to enable HW PMC however. Lot of caveats and limitations.

[Using Virtual CPU Performance Monitoring Counters (2030221)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2030221)